# Bug in account reputation association?

Tags: bug, status-completed, association-bonus

I found out recently that if you have over 200 rep in a stackexchange community, you are supposed to receive +100 rep on all stackexchange sites you are a part of. Despite having over 300 rep on stackoverflow, none of the other sites I'm part of (crossvalidated, data science, mathematics, etc) seem to show this association rep. Am I missing something? I tried to post a comment today on a a question in the math site, and couldn't because I didn't have 50 rep.

Comment: It appears the recalculation of question upvotes did not trigger association bonuses if the user would qualify now. Before that you only had 189 reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know if there are any plans to fix it? Should I tag someone? Or maybe this is just how it is.

Comment: I thought this was fixed already: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391591

Comment: It looks like this has been fixed: as of 3 hours ago I received points in each of my linked accounts.

Comment: @animuson [same bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391583/why-did-i-not-receive-the-reputation-bonus) on MSO marked as completed, why this one isn't? Any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed as of December 12, 2019.