# Have multiple site accounts and enough reputation to qualify for the association bonus, but didn't receive it

Tags: bug, status-completed, association-bonus

Is it still a thing? I don’t think I’ve ever seen it.

- Ask Ubuntu: 264
- Meta SE: 81
- Linguistics: 56
- Area 51: 51 (spooky!)
- Super User: 33
- Unix & Linux: 3
- Stack Overflow | User Experience | Bicyles | Video Production | Music: Theory & Practice | Retrocomputing | Genealogy & Family History | Joomla: 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bug in account reputation association?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340026/bug-in-account-reputation-association)

Comment: A couple of people have suggested that [Bug in account reputation association?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340026/bug-in-account-reputation-association) answers my question. The ultimate answer there is “It looks like this has been fixed” so unless there’s some technical reason I should accept that I’d say that doesn’t entirely answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for the delay. I still haven't had a chance to dig into a fix for all affected users, but I kicked off a manual bonus grant for your account.

If anyone else is encountering the same problem, please [contact us](/contact) and we'll fix it for you.