# Why do some users (still) not have the association bonus?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts, association-bonus

From [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391583/10784814) on Meta SO I understand that the change in the value of question upvotes from +5 to +10 led to a bug resulting in some users not receiving the association bonuses. That question is now marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

But, I came across [this user](https://stackexchange.com/users/5753992/ayudh?tab=accounts) who has over 200 reputation on SO but who has not been given the association bonuses on their other accounts.

So, I suppose this means that this bug has still not been resolved completely?

Comment: Regarding the downvotes, did I do something incorrectly? If I should ask this somewhere else or in a different manner, then please let me know. I'll be happy to correct myself.

Comment: As the answer on [Have multiple site accounts and enough reputation to qualify for the association bonus, but didn't receive it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341944/have-multiple-site-accounts-and-enough-reputation-to-qualify-for-the-association) says, the developers haven't yet had time to dig into a proper fix.

Comment: As far as the downvotes here, I don't really know. I'd imagine at least one is because people are resentful of the revaluation and downvoting bug reports for a new feature that they disagree with because they don't want it "fixed".

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks for the link! I have now upvoted the linked post - it's kind of unexpected that there are contradicting answers about whether the bug is fully resolved or not. In any case, this question is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I had no idea that such reasons exist, thanks for enlightening me about that too.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Not intended. When it was first fixed, they thought it fixed everything. Then we realized there’s a subset edge case that still is outstanding.

Comment: @Catija What is the subset edge case?